# bulk assign ADO Tasks under the same User Story

Tags: azure, azure-devops

This question is about Microsoft Azure DevOps Kanban Board.
Hi dear MS Azure DevOps experts, can someone please reply how to bulk assign ADO Tasks under the same User Story? I have User Story, a bunch of Tasks under it. All of the tasks need to be assigned to me and I don't want to assign one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can someone please reply how to bulk assign ADO Tasks under the same User Story?

The answer is yes.

Azure devops supports [Bulk edit multi-selected work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=azure-devops#bulk-edit-multi-selected-work-items) at this moment:

> To start a bulk edit, begin by multi-selecting the work items you want
> to modify, either from the query results or the backlog. You can craft
> your query using the query editor or search box.
>
> Multi-select of work items on the backlog and sprint backlogs works in
> the same way as multi-select works within query results.
>
> You can use bulk modify by selecting work items from the backlog page
> or query results list. From the backlog page context menu, you can
> change the backlog priority of several items (Change position or Move
> to position), assign them to a team member, move them to a different
> sprint, or map them to a feature.
>
> The menu options available to you change depending on the platform you
> work from and whether you work from a backlog page or query results
> list.

And there is option [Reassign work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=azure-devops#reassign-work-items), we could quickly assign them to a member of your team or to another sprint or iteration.

Besides, we could also bulk add or modify work items with **Excel**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Check this document [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process) for some more details.